# Interpreting a crash log without references to App functions/classes

Tags: ios, crash

I'm getting a "random" crash on my last application (around the 2% of the users seems to experience the crash) but I'm not able to find any useful info from the crash logs. It seems that I don't have any reference to my code and I find extremely difficult to understand what is going on and how this crash is generated... I paste here the relevant part of the crash log, any hints or thoughts about it? is there anything obvious that I'm missing ...

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x18266d900 __exceptionPreprocess + 124 (NSException.m:162)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x181cdbf80 objc_exception_throw + 56 (objc-exception.mm:531)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x18266d7d0 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 108 (NSException.m:131)
3   Foundation                      0x182fe099c -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 112 (NSException.m:152)
4   UIKit                           0x187608ac0 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 3216 (UIApplication.m:3315)
5   UIKit                           0x1876055c0 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 168 (UIApplication.m:2662)
6   FrontBoardServices              0x183c23790 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 184 (FBSSerialQueue.m:157)
7   FrontBoardServices              0x183c23b10 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56 (FBSSerialQueue.m:204)
8   CoreFoundation                  0x182624efc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24 (CFRunLoop.c:1761)
9   CoreFoundation                  0x182624990 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540 (CFRunLoop.c:1807)
10  CoreFoundation                  0x182622690 __CFRunLoopRun + 724 (CFRunLoop.c:2536)
11  CoreFoundation                  0x182551680 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384 (CFRunLoop.c:2814)
12  UIKit                           0x1873ce580 -[UIApplication _run] + 460 (UIApplication.m:2503)
13  UIKit                           0x1873c8d90 UIApplicationMain + 204 (UIApplication.m:3681)
14  KickLow                         0x100153604 0x100024000 + 1242628
15  libdyld.dylib                   0x1820f28b8 start + 4 (start_glue.s:80)

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182210140 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001822d8ef8 pthread_kill + 112 (pthread.c:1247)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000182181dac abort + 140 (abort.c:91)
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000181cb53f4 abort_message + 132 (abort_message.cpp:47)
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000181cd1e98 default_terminate_handler() + 304 (cxa_default_handlers.cpp:67)
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000181cdc248 _objc_terminate() + 124 (objc-exception.mm:678)
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000181ccef44 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16 (cxa_handlers.cpp:62)
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000181cceb10 __cxa_rethrow + 144 (cxa_exception.cpp:480)
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000181cdc120 objc_exception_rethrow + 44 (objc-exception.mm:581)
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182551728 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552 (CFRunLoop.c:2827)
10  UIKit                           0x00000001873ce580 -[UIApplication _run] + 460 (UIApplication.m:2503)
11  UIKit                           0x00000001873c8d90 UIApplicationMain + 204 (UIApplication.m:3681)
12  KickLow                         0x0000000100153604 0x100024000 + 1242628
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001820f28b8 start + 4 (start_glue.s:80)
```

Comment: Are you using notifications? If so make sure that they are properly removed when de-allocating a receiver.

Comment: Your issue seem same to [weird crash when launching app from Notification Center](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26371462/weird-crash-when-launching-app-from-notification-center)

Comment: @aman.sood you are right. Please fill an answer so that you can get the bounty.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Moved my comment as answer. @MatterGoal glad to know it helped.

Your issue seem similar to [weird crash when launching app from Notification Center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26371462/weird-crash-when-launching-app-from-notification-center)

> Either your code or a third-party library you are using is manually spinning the runloop. This is causing -workspaceDidEndTransaction: to be called re-entrantly and triggers a use after free. If you set a breakpoint on -[NSRunLoop runMode:beforeDate:] and -[NSRunLoop runUntilDate:], it should hit with the guilty code being on the previous stack frame.
>
> While manually spinning the run loop is never recommended, if you can
> delay doing it until your application finishes starting up (all the
> launch app delegate calls received) you should avoid hitting this
> crash.

Comment: Please include more than just a link. As it currently stands, this does not qualify as an answer.

Comment: modified answer to include more details

Comment: The answer has been modified, can you kindly remove your downvote.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of a question already asked, which is the exact question you are referencing in both your comment, and copying in your answer. Posting this answer is incorrect, leaving a comment referring to the question that this is a duplicate of, is correct. I'm sorry, but my down-vote remains.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the disassembly of the `-[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:]` method, here is what we find out:

```
0x111ef155d <+3038>: movq   0xd166b4(%rip), %rdi      ; (void *)0x0000000111ce4b10: NSAssertionHandler
0x111ef1564 <+3045>: movq   0xce0bcd(%rip), %rsi      ; "currentHandler"
0x111ef156b <+3052>: callq  *0xd64c5f(%rip)           ; (void *)0x0000000113e36800: objc_msgSend
0x111ef1571 <+3058>: movq   %rax, %rdi
0x111ef1574 <+3061>: callq  0x1129c0046               ; symbol stub for: objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue
0x111ef1579 <+3066>: movq   %rax, %r15
0x111ef157c <+3069>: leaq   0xda427d(%rip), %rax      ; @"Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch"
0x111ef1583 <+3076>: movq   %rax, (%rsp)
0x111ef1587 <+3080>: movl   $0xd3c, %r9d              ; imm = 0xD3C 
0x111ef158d <+3086>: xorl   %eax, %eax
0x111ef158f <+3088>: movq   %r15, %rdi
0x111ef1592 <+3091>: movq   0xce0ba7(%rip), %rsi      ; "handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:"
```

So it seems your app is creating a window with no root view controller. Perhaps your view controller fails to create.